# I keep getting "bsdtar: Failed to set file flags" when I try do pull base

Tags: docker

I wanted to start playing with *docker* last night but couldn't get it working. I would run the simple command `docker pull base` and it would take its time to download 98M of data. Then it would complain with several lines of `./usr/blah/foobar bsdtar: Failed to set file flags`. If I would try it again, the download would start over from the beginning, not even resume or discover that it had already finished earlier.

What would I need to do to get this working?

My root filesystem was a btrfs filesystem. Could this be causing the problem?

If someone could tell me *why* btrfs was a problem, that would be a better answer than just fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out btrfs *was* causing the problem. I moved my root over to an ext4 filesystem, and now `docker pull base` works just fine and `docker run -i -t base /bin/bash` gives me a nice command prompt.

Comment: They seem to be aware of the problem. https://twitter.com/getdocker/status/327105726659039233

Comment: getting the same errors when installing Arch linux rootfs on an SDcard for a raspberry pi. Also from bsdtar.

Comment: Is that rootfs also using btrfs?